# Adobe illustrator : Problem with saving for web

Tags: adobe-illustrator, save

Ok guys I'm stuck here when i try to save for web adobe illustrator shows elements outside the artboard and if there is no elements outside the artboard illustrator tries to crop the image so there is no space between the lines of the artboard and the element inside the artboard 
here is what happens

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the **Save for Web** options, be sure to tick the **Clip to Artboard** option in the **Image Size** section:

[image]